# SQL CTE for one-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I have two tables

1) Is the applicant name so it would look like this

```
ID | ApplicantName
_____________________________
1  | 'Joe Schmoe'    
2  | 'Jimmy Dean'
```

2) Is the applicants questions so it would look like this

```
ID | ApplicantId | QuestionId | QuestionAnswer
_________________________________________________
1  |      1      |     1      |   'PF CHANGS'
2  |      1      |     2      |   'Toyota'
3  |      2      |     1      |   'Burger King'
4  |      2      |     2      |   'Honda'
```

So I query it and I get these results:

```
ApplicantName | QuestionId | QuestionAnswer
_________________________________________________
'Joe Schmoe'  |     1      |   'PF CHANGS'
'Joe Schmoe'  |     2      |   'Toyota'
'Jimmy Dean'  |     1      |   'Burger King'
'Jimmy Dean'  |     2      |   'Honda'
```

But that's not what I want I want something like this if possible using the AS clause:

```
ApplicantName | Answer1       |  Answer2
_________________________________________________
'Joe Schmoe'  | 'PF CHANGS'   | 'Toyota'
'Jimmy Dean'  | 'Burger King' | 'Honda'
```

I have no idea how to achieve this.

I've looked up things like MAx() and COUNT() but those don't work something about aggregates not working.

```
-- I GUESS THIS IS AS CLOSE AS I GOT BUT IT FAILS

SELECT g.ApplicantName,  MAX(CAST(c.QuestionAnswer as varchar(MAX))) AS Questions
FROM Forms f
INNER JOIN GeneralQuestions g ON f.FormId = g.FormId
LEFT JOIN CustomQuestions c ON f.FormId = c.FormId
GROUP BY c.QuestionAnswer
--ORDER BY g.ApplicantName ASC
```

Comment: You want this implemented with Common Table Expressions?

Comment: @RJ As long as it works I don't using another solution

Comment: How many columns?

Comment: Please disable your CAPS LOCK when posting. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and it won't get you help any faster. It's also somewhat impolite to SHOUT AT US for attention. Thanks.

Comment: This call a pivot or a crosstab. One of the caveats to doing this is whether you know what and how many columns you have in advance.

Comment: @Dale thanks it did I added Rjs solution as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CTEs and joins:

```
with cteAppl(id, name)
as
(
    select
        id, name
    from
    (
        values
          (1,  'Joe Schmoe'),   
          (2,  'Jimmy Dean') 
    ) vals(id, name)
),
ctePositions(applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer)
as
(
    select 
        applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer
    from
    (
        values
          (1, 1,  'PF CHANGS'),
          (1, 2,  'Toyota'),
          (2, 1,   'Burger King'),
          (2, 2,  'Honda')
    ) vals(applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer)
),
ctePositions1(applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer)
as
(
    select 
        applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer
    from
        ctePositions
    where
        questionID = 1
),
ctePositions2(applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer)
as
(
    select 
        applicantID, questionID, questionAnswer
    from
        ctePositions
    where
        questionID = 2
)
select
    a.[name], 
    p1.questionAnswer as Answer1,
    case when p2.questionAnswer is null then '' else p2.questionAnswer end as Answer2
from
    cteAppl a
inner join
    ctePositions1 p1 on a.id = p1.applicantID
left join
    ctePositions2 p2 on a.id = p2.applicantID
```

With the T-SQL PIVOT operator:

```
with cteAppl(id, [name])
as
(
    select
        id, name
    from
    (
        values
          (1,  'Joe Schmoe'),   
          (2,  'Jimmy Dean') ,
    ) vals(id, name)
),
ctePositions(applicantID, answerID, questionAnswer)
as
(
    select 
        applicantID, answerID, questionAnswer
    from
    (
        values
          (1, 1,  'PF CHANGS'),
          (1, 2,  'Toyota'),
          (2, 1,  'Burger King'),
          (2, 2,  'Honda'),
    ) vals(applicantID, answerID, questionAnswer)
)
select
    cpvt.applicantName,
    cp1.questionAnswer as [Answer1],
    cp2.questionAnswer as [Answer2]  
from
(
    select
        [name],
        applicantID,
        pvt.answer1,
        pvt.answer2
    from
    (
        select
            a.[name],
            p.applicantID,      
            case 
                when p.answerID = 1 then 'answer1'
                when p.answerID = 2 then 'answer2'
                else ''
            end as generatedColumnName, 
            p.answerID
        from
            cteAppl a
        inner join
            ctePositions p on a.id = p.ApplicantID
    ) as st ([name], applicantID, [generatedColumnName], [answerID])
    PIVOT 
    (
           MAX(st.answerID) -- Must use an aggregate function here
           for generatedColumnName in ([answer1], [answer2]) 
    ) as pvt
) cpvt (applicantName, applicantID, answer1ID, answer2ID)
left join
    ctePositions cp1 on cp1.applicantID = cpvt.applicantID and cp1.answerID = cpvt.answer1ID
left join
    ctePositions cp2 on cp2.applicantID = cpvt.applicantID and cp2.answerID = cpvt.answer2ID
```